# CMD/Powershell: Copy files with partial path wildcards

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I want to implement the following functionality using either the Windows Command Prompt, Powershell, or a combination of the two:

Suppose we are given a source directory, `sourcedir` and a destination directory `destinationdir`, and we want to copy files, recursively, from the source to the destination.

We are also given a wildcard filter like so `*/foo/bar/*`; the filter means find all files in `sourcedir` that contain `/foo/bar/` anywhere in its path. For instance, `sourcedir/foo/bar/file1.txt`, and `sourcedir/baz/foo/bar/file2.txt` will be copied, while `sourcedir/foo/baz/bar/file3.txt` will not be copied.

Comment: Choose a language then think about how it might do it, try a few things, then post problems you are having to one of the groups.

Comment: ??? it's a requirement for a task I'm doing at work and the whole thing is hung up on this step. I've tried a few approaches involving Get-ChildItem and Where-Object, neither have really worked.

Comment: Actually, the root of the problem is neither Command Prompt or Powershell seem to support the regular `**/` partial path wildcard

Answer (score 1):

Right, figured this out with a bunch of random stuff. Turns out `*/foo/bar/*` partial path does work in Get-ChildItem:

`Get-ChildItem -Path "$($sourcedir)\$($filter)" -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination $destinationdir`

Comment: May I suggest you start using either PowerShell [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-6) or .Net [[System.IO.Path]::Combine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.7.2) to concatenate file paths. Using either will ensure the path you construct is syntactically correct. (you don't 'miss' a backslash by mistake)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
copy-Item $SourceDir $DestinationDir -recurse
```

Comment: This worked smoothly for me and is the simplest solution here. I simply put the full paths starting from the root and used wildcards in the source path as needed. Thanks!